# asp.net c# gridview1 if row selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have gridview1 in my asp.net application that returns number of rows and I want to make sure that one row is selected so I searched online for answers and I find something like this:

```
if (usersGrid.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
```

This would be good, but my gridview1 object only shows "SelectedRow" instead of "SelectedRows" and I'm not able to get the count property from the SelectedRow object. What's the explanation for this and how can I make sure one row record is selected?

Comment: are you allowing for the gridview to be multi select..?

Comment: I don't know how to do that so unless it is enabled by default, my answer is no. thanks.

Comment: look at the datagridview's properties `multiselect`

Comment: It is odd. When I navigate top to bottom in the GridView1 control's properties window, I don't see the multiselect option. Which category should it be under? I don't think I missed it - double checked.

Comment: is this winforms or webforms.? if it's web page check here - https://www.codeproject.com/articles/831115/how-to-get-multiple-selected-rows-from-gridview-in otherwise start using google to do a search on MultiSelect in GridView